# Android Drag and Drop in a Horizontal LinearLayout

Tags: android, drag-and-drop

I'm trying to implement a drag and drop function in my application.

I'm using a LinearLayout to display the items horizontally (combined with HorizontalScrollView for scrolling).

Now I need to implement a drag-and-drop function wherein the user needs to long press an item and user can start dragging to move the item.

However, based on what I got so far, setting the margin in a linearlayout will also move the other items in the layout. I need only the selected item to be moved.

How can I achieve this? Should I use another ViewGroup? (though I need the horizontal scrolling function)

Comment: why the downvote? is there something wrong with my question?

Comment: have you found it? +1

Comment: Did you find it?